# MDX: get attribute from a slowly changing dimension in a cell

Tags: ssas, mdx

I need to build a report that shows day-to-day changes in the cube. E.g. for account we show the balance on day X and balance on day Y. I achieve it with something like this:

```
WITH
MEMBER OldBalance AS ([Balance], [Date].[Date].[2013-05-01]) -- start date
MEMBER NewBalance AS ([Balance], [Date].[Date].[2013-05-04]) -- end date
SELECT {OldBalance, NewBalance} ON COLUMNS
[Account].[AccountNumber].[AccountNumber] ON ROWS
FROM TheCube
```

This shows two columns for each account, everyone's happy:

```
        OldBalance   NewBalance
ACT123   1050.25        1048.29
ACT345    950.08        1421.92
```

In addition to account number, [Account] dimension also has SalesRepName as an attribute, and the value of SalesRepName may change over time, making [Account] a slowly changing dimension. What I want to see is something along the lines of:

```
        OldBalance   NewBalance  OldSalesRep  NewSalesRep
ACT123   1050.25        1048.29  John Smith   John Smith
ACT345    950.08        1421.92  John Smith   George Fisher
```

But I have no idea how to achieve this in MDX, and whether it is even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use something like `TopCount` and then `Item`:
`WITH
MEMBER [Date].[Date].StartDate AS [Date].[Date].[2013-05-01]
MEMBER [Date].[Date].EndDate AS [Date].[Date].[2013-05-04]
MEMBER OldBalance AS ([Balance], [Date].[Date].StartDate)
MEMBER NewBalance AS ([Balance], [Date].[Date].EndDate)
MEMBER OldSalesRep AS 
    TopCount(
        NonEmpty(
            ([Account].[SalesRep].[SalesRep], [Date].[Date].StartDate, 
            [Account].[AccountNumber].CurrentMember), [Balance]), 
        1)
    .Item(0).Item(0).Properties("Caption")
MEMBER NewSalesRep AS 
    TopCount(
        NonEmpty(
            ([Account].[SalesRep].[SalesRep], [Date].[Date].EndDate, 
            [Account].[AccountNumber].CurrentMember), [Balance]), 
        1)
    .Item(0).Item(0).Properties("Caption")
SELECT {OldBalance, NewBalance, OldSalesRep, NewSalesRep} ON COLUMNS
[Account].[AccountNumber].[AccountNumber] ON ROWS
FROM TheCube`

Keep in mind, however, that on large cubes the performance may be not that good.